# Software to build dashboards from MongoDB data

Tags: dashboard, mongodb

Is there any cloud or self-hosted tool that I can connect to my DB, build queries, and then create beautiful dashboards with plots, tables, and so on with the data retrieved from the queries?

The database is currently MongoDB. I don't know if services like Datadog for example suit my necessity, because they talk about data retention and stuff like that, but I don't need any data retention because my data is in my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something Open Source, Free and on-premises have a look at [Metabase](http://Metabase.com).

It takes really just 5 minutes, if not under to get your first graph on the screen. It supports MongoDB but it supports the following databases as well:

- MySQL
- Postgres
- SQL Server
- AWS Redshift
- Google BigQuery
- Druid
- H2
- SQLite
- Oracle
- Crate
- Google Analytics
- Vertica

I've used it visualize data from our Service Desk software that is based on MySQL. It's been updated regularly and it's actively maintained.

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly what I was looking for. Trying it right now!

Comment: Could you please focus on the asker's need, rather than write a big list of supported databases, as the asker only has MongoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Redash](https://redash.io/) supports MongoDB and many other data sources. It provides several types of charts and also dynamic dashboards.

Here a [sample](https://redash.io/assets/images/temp/redash_screenshot_vis-slide-2.png).